# Not filling NaN values in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nan

Lets say I have the following df:

```
      quantity#1    taxsubtotal#1    taxrate#1    quantity#2    taxsubtotal#2    taxrate#2
--  ------------  ---------------  -----------  ------------  ---------------  -----------
 0           nan             1.05           21           nan            nan            nan
 2             1             2.1            21             1              1.8            9
 6             1             0               0           nan              nan            nan
13             1             0.9             9             1              1.8            9
21             1            23.4             9             1              2.7            9
```

I don't want to write the NaN values to the columns of a df:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({
'InvoiceLine1':"""
    <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="ZZ">"""+dftaxitems1['quantity#1'].astype(str)+"""</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">"""+dftaxitems1['taxsubtotal#1'].astype(str)+"""</cbc:TaxAmount>
          <cbc:Percent>"""+dftaxitems1['taxrate#1'].astype(str)+"""</cbc:Percent>""",
'InvoiceLine2':"""
    <cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="ZZ">"""+dftaxitems1['quantity#2'].astype(str)+"""</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="EUR">"""+dftaxitems1['taxsubtotal#2'].astype(str)+"""</cbc:TaxAmount>
          <cbc:Percent>"""+dftaxitems1['taxrate#2'].astype(str)+"""</cbc:Percent>""",
})
```

Assessing the type of nan:

```
type:
type(dftaxitems['quantity#2'][0])
numpy.float64
```

Getting the folllowing output:

```
    InvoiceLine1                                       InvoiceLine2
0   \n <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>\n <cbc:InvoicedQua... \n <cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>\n <cbc:InvoicedQua...
2   \n <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>\n <cbc:InvoicedQua... \n <cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>\n <cbc:InvoicedQua...
6   \n <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>\n <cbc:InvoicedQua... \n <cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>\n <cbc:InvoicedQua...
13  \n <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>\n <cbc:InvoicedQua... \n <cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>\n <cbc:InvoicedQua...
21  \n <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>\n <cbc:InvoicedQua... \n <cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>\n <cbc:InvoicedQua...
```

Desired output:

```
    InvoiceLine1                                       InvoiceLine2
0   \n <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>\n <cbc:InvoicedQua... 
2   \n <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>\n <cbc:InvoicedQua... \n <cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>\n <cbc:InvoicedQua...
6   \n <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>\n <cbc:InvoicedQua... 
13  \n <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>\n <cbc:InvoicedQua... \n <cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>\n <cbc:InvoicedQua...
21  \n <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>\n <cbc:InvoicedQua... \n <cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>\n <cbc:InvoicedQua...
```

`df3.fillna('')` did not work!

What could help according to you guys :)?

I've tried to transform all values to np.nan so that it can be accurately deleted in  the new df

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first convert values to strings and then empty strings to missing values:

```
df = df.astype(str).replace('', np.nan)
```

and then remove `.astype(str)` later like `dftaxitems1['quantity#1'].astype(str)`.

Test:

```
dftaxitems1 = pd.DataFrame({'quantity#1': ['', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]})
dftaxitems1 = dftaxitems1.astype(str).replace('', np.nan)

s = """<cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="ZZ">"""+dftaxitems1['quantity#1']+"""</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>"""
 
print (s)
0                                                  NaN
1    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="ZZ">1.0</cbc:I...
2    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="ZZ">1.0</cbc:I...
3    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="ZZ">1.0</cbc:I...
4    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="ZZ">1.0</cbc:I...
Name: quantity#1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jezreal however did not work :(. The values are blank in the initial DF but they still get written to the df3 dataframe unfortunately

Comment: as in the values should be blank for the first and third row but aren't

Comment: @Max - what means blank ? empty string? `nan` string? Misisng value `np.nan` ? All is something different.

Comment: @Max - Is possible convert some column with this values to list see what is it? e. g `print (df['quantity#2'].head(10).tolist())`

Comment: sorry! Here you go: 
['', 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
this was after your code : df = df.replace('nan', '')

Comment: @Max - So need `df = df.replace('', np.nan)`  ?

Comment: So I would like the row to be entirely empty as in the desired output --> I think because of the  .astype(str) asset  df = df.replace('nan', '') it only removes the 'nan' value in the df3 dataframe

Comment: When I remove the .tostring() I get an error however

Comment: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230407/discussion-between-max-and-jezrael).

Comment: @Max - Can you try `df = df.astype(str).replace('', np.nan)` ?

Comment: @Max - super! Happy coding!